# Rules around text inflation algorithm (text-size-adjust css)

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I've recently encountered a seemingly common issue where the font size of my simple text element in a relatively simple markup gets inflated when viewing it in landscape mode on (iPhone 6).
A little googling and the answer is to use the following css to stop it from auto inflating.

`html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}`

But before I apply this to my web page, I would like a better understanding of the algorithm it uses to decide whether to inflate the font-size or not.
For my simple markup, its only 2 out of 10 text elements are inflated.  A little bit of trail and error, it seems that `inline-block` elements are not inflated and "some" `block` elements are.
Also viewing a common complexed website like `https://www.bbc.co.uk`, they don't seem to use the `text-size-adjust` anywhere, but none of their text seems to get inflated in landscape.
I know the `text-size-adjust` is still an experimental feature, so don't want to apply that blanket rule on the whole page.  I could target just the problem text element, but before I do this I just want a better understanding of this problem.
I assume that some clever guy thought it was a good idea to auto inflate text in landscape, so I don't want to disable this without a good reason.

Thanks